# Row Count in AgGrid

Tags: ag-grid

I want show the row count in my AgGrid, but I got a problem.

```
    ngOnInit() { 
      console.log(this.gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowCount());
    }
```

Error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDisplayedRowCount' of undefined
    at ProjectListComponent.webpackJsonp../src/app/project-list/project-list.component.ts.ProjectListComponent.ngOnInit (project-list.component.ts:178)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12411)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13935)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13878)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14771)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14712)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ProjectListComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14697)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13844)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
```

Api the AgGrid:

```
getDisplayedRowCount()  Returns the total number of displayed rows.
```

I don't understand why I have this problem...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(You mention ngOnInit so I assume you are using Angular)
The problem is that the api is not available in `ngOnInit`. You should listen for the `gridReady` event if you need the grid api.

> **gridReady:** ag-Grid has initialised. Use this event if, for example, you need to use the grid's API to fix the columns to size.
>   [Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#miscellaneous)

html:

```
<ag-grid-angular   style="width: 100%; height: 372px;"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady()">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

component ts:

```
onGridReady(params: any) {
  console.log('grid ready');
  console.log(this.gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowCount());
}
```

You should also keep in mind that there is a note on [this site](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-more-details/):

> Sometimes the `gridReady` grid event can fire before the Angular
>   component is ready to receive it, so in an Angular environment its
>   safer to rely on `AfterViewInit` instead before using the API.

Despite that I never had any problems using the `gridReady` event.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ag-grid react component then use the below procedure to get the count

```
<AgGridReact
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    rowData={rowData}
    defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
    onGridReady={onGridReady}
></AgGridReact>


const onGridReady = (params) => {
        setRow(params.api.getDisplayedRowCount());
    };
```